# Swing Game, How can I place game window layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm making Tetris with Swing and I would like to place the game board in the middle of the screen with fixed dimensions and 1 or 2 panel next to it.
I would like to have the tetris game have some margin from the JFrame and still start from 0,0 positions inside a container if possible.

The goal:

[image]

I've tried with adding game to `JPanel` and centering it but then the game wont display.

My code:

```
public class Window {

public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    game.start();
}
}
```

The centered fixed layout I've found but didnt work:

```
JFrame Frame = new JFrame("CenterFrame");
    Frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    Frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));// dim

    JPanel FixedPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    FixedPanel.setPreferredSize(Frame.getSize());

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    FixedPanel.add(myPanel);
    Frame.add(FixedPanel);
    Frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) *"The centered fixed layout I've found:"* Is that the solution to the problem? If so, it should not be part of the question, but posted as an answer. 4) I'd use one of two approaches for this a) put the main UI in a `GridBagLayout` with no constraint. ..

Comment: .. It will be centered.  b) assign an empty border to the main UI, add it to the frame, set the frame non-resizable, then pack the top level container (the window or frame).

Comment: *"The centered fixed layout I've found **but didnt work:**"* OK, that answers the 3rd point. How/why did it not work?

Comment: Would you mind showing an example? The centered fixed layout code with JPanel didnt even display the game. Im not sure why.

Comment: *"Would you mind showing an example?"* I'll look at the problem more closely once I've seen the MCVE/SSCCE & you've clarified whether the top level window is resizable.

Comment: The Jframe should not be resizable.

Comment: *"The Jframe should not be resizable"* One out of two ain't bad, but it's not enough to elicit more help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you wanted?

```
private void initGameFrame(int gameWidth, int height, int scoreWidth, int border, String title) {
    //game frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(gameWidth + scoreWidth, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 10));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    // Game panel
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    gamePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gameWidth, height));
    gamePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    // Score panel
    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
    scorePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scorePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE / 2, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    scorePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scoreWidth, height));
    scorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    scorePanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    // game canvas
    RunnableCanvas game = new RunnableCanvas(gameWidth, height);
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    game.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    gamePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gamePanel.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scorePanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // your real game thread should be here 
    Thread gameThread = new Thread(game);
    gameThread.start(); 
}
```

And your Runnable Canvas:

```
public class RunnableCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    int width = 300;
    int height = 400; 

    public RunnableCanvas(int width, int height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running");
    }

    @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(width, height);
   }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
   }
}
```

Comment: For margins yes that could work, but I want the game to be added inside the "myPanel". It still doesnt display if I add "myPanel.add(game);       game.start();"

Comment: Is your Game class a JComponent?

Comment: No I don't think so , it extends Canvas and implements Runnable